# How to get image binary data and show it?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In my angular application I'm integrating the google authentication where I need to display a QR code that is generated on server side.

How using angular `$http.get` I can receive the binary data of the image and assign it to an existing `<img />` object using  `ng-src` or something else?

What format shall be chosen to send data from server? raw binary `.png` data or maybe `base64`?

Any ideas are appreciated?

P.S. I cannot generate and store the image on server and just send the link.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the API from http://chart.apis.google.com/chart. If that's the case, you can simply set your fully formed query string as the img src, and it should load the png. I've done this before for creating bitcoin QR's

i.e. if this is your API query

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chld=L|1&choe=ISO-8859-1&chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=bitcoin:4324234324dsf?amount=453%26label=dsfsdf%26message=sdfdsf

It should also work as the img src, even though it has no .png file extension. I'm not sure if it will work with ng-src though, so just create your image tag like

[image]

Comment: No, I'm using this url `https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/{0}%3Fsecret%3D{1}` to get the QR code for a given identity, and using it on the client side would create a security breach as I'd have to let client know the Secret string used.

Comment: Then I would just add an endpoint that accepts your client params, generates the QR on google, publishes the file to S3, then returns a URL. You'll want to have some kind of intermediary file so that you're not calling Google APIs on every request for the file unless it's a once off thing.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid, generation of intermediate files :)

Comment: I think I've found a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235846/display-binary-image-from-db-to-angular-partial-view, experimenting.